# Dynamic size of UIScrollView with UINavigationBar

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uiscrollview, uinavigationbar

I was wondering if there is simple or neat way to achieve `UIScrollView` with different size and origin of frame depending on page number? I want to show navigation bar on first page, but hide it on other pages.
First idea that came to my mind is to use `scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` method, where I can set frame origin and size through `setFrame:(CGRect)`.
It's quite a mess, beacuse I'm defining this `scrollView` elsewhere and with initial `ContentSize` and number of pages, etc. So actually, after loading whole view I have to deal with frame changes when user scrolls view.
**What I have now:**

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    CGFloat pageWidth = self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
    int page = floor((self.scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
    self.pageController.currentPage = page;
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:page];
    if (page) {
        [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, -44, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height + 44)];
        [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        [self.scrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.scrollView.frame.size.width, self.scrollView.frame.size.height)];
        [self.scrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    }else{
        [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
        [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        [self.scrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.scrollView.frame.size.width, self.scrollView.frame.size.height)];
        [self.scrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    }
}
```

Colours are only for visual debugging. Think of it as Springboard with from time to time appearing navigation bar. So `scrollView` is a part of view, not the whole view. Not sure if idea is worth anything, but I'm not the one calling shots, so I'm trying to find anything. Is it the way?

Answer (score 0):

I finally came up with this (same code is put inside `-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:`)

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
NSLog(@"HomeVC: viewWillAppear");
CGFloat pageWidth = self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
int page = floor((self.scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
self.pageController.currentPage = page;
if (page > 0) {
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
    [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height + 44)];
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [self.scrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, HOMESCREEN_WIDTH, HOMESCREEN_HEIGHT + 44)];
    [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(HOMESCREEN_WIDTH * SCREEN, HOMESCREEN_HEIGHT + 44)];
    [self.scrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [self.pageController setCenter:CGPointMake(HOMESCREEN_WIDTH/2, self.scrollView.frame.size.height + 5)];
}else{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
    [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [self.scrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, HOMESCREEN_WIDTH, HOMESCREEN_HEIGHT)];
    [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(HOMESCREEN_WIDTH * SCREEN, HOMESCREEN_HEIGHT)];
    [self.scrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [self.pageController setCenter:CGPointMake(HOMESCREEN_WIDTH/2, self.scrollView.frame.size.height + 5)];
}
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES animated:YES];
}
```

It is working!